# Mean average precision - python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, information-retrieval

I am calculating mean average precision at top k retrieve objects. Here is my code. At this stage, I am computing *R@K*. 
The code read the two lists from `csv` files, then take a sample from a list, compute euclidean distance with all samples from other list, sort them and finally take top k objects to see if the object is available in the retrieved samples.

```
import csv
from scipy.spatial import distance
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from numpy import dot
from numpy.linalg import norm
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler  
import numpy as np
from numpy import array


def parse_features_from_csv(csv_file):
    feat_lst = []
    id_lst = []
    row_lst = []
    with open(csv_file) as fr:
        reader = csv.reader(fr, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            s_feat = row[:-1]
            identifier = row[-1]
            s_feat = [float(i) for i in s_feat]
            feat_lst.append(s_feat)
            id_lst.append(identifier)
            row_lst.append(row[-1])
    return feat_lst, id_lst,row_lst


def compute_distances(et_item, feat_lst, id_lst):
    dist_list = []
    for id_img_item, img_item in enumerate(feat_lst):
        dist = distance.euclidean(img_item,et_item)
        #print (dist)
        dist_list.append((id_lst[id_img_item], dist))
    return dist_list


def main():
    top_k = 10
    feat_file = "list_1.csv"
    test_file = "list_2.csv"
    et_feat_lst, et_id_list, _ = parse_features_from_csv(test_file)
    feat_list, id_list,row_lst_et = parse_features_from_csv(feat_file)



    print (len(feat_list))
    print (len(et_feat_lst))




    correct = 0
    for id_et_item, et_item in enumerate(et_feat_lst):
        distances = compute_distances(et_item, feat_list, row_lst_et)
        sort_dst = sorted(distances, key=lambda x: x[1])

        #print("Target: " + et_id_list[id_et_item] + ", Distances: " + str(sort_dst[:top_k]))

        eucl_dist = sort_dst[:top_k]
        gt = et_id_list[id_et_item]
        for idx in eucl_dist:
            tar = idx[0]        
            if gt == tar:
                correct+= 1
                break

        print ("correct", str(correct) + '/' +  str(id_et_item))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Can some one tell how I can use `sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score`
function to compute Mean average precision for top K retrieved objects.
I have confusion related to `(y_true, y_scores)` . I would appreciate if someone can explain these two parametres of the function.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question. Do you want to calculate the Precision@K?

Comment: mean average precision@K. @Eduardo

Comment: @cswah I am also confused by the `y_scores` documentation in sklearn. However, as I understand mAP, there is no "@k" component since you are averaging the precision at all values of k. You might need to re-work your question for others to get that distinction

Comment: Could you include some sample data?